# SQL запрос выбираются все данные

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с запросом.

запрос вида

```
SELECT i.*,
       p.*
FROM images i,
     products p
WHERE p.product_id=i.product_id
  AND p.timeadded=1393282800
  AND i.color!=0
  AND p.active=1
  AND p.maker_id=32
  AND p.timeadded!=0
  OR (i.product_id IN (3598))
```

если запрос без OR (i.product_id IN (3598)) - то все работает нормально, а с этим куском выводится очень много всего (может даже вообще все записи).

Где ошибка? Мне важно, чтобы было соблюдено условие: выбрать то, что было до OR (i.product_id IN (3598)), а также, выбрать OR (i.product_id IN (3598))

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: так на то он и OR, чтобы выбирать что-то одно =)

Comment: а AND тут тем более не подходит) or не совсем что-то одно выводит, он говорит: может быть так или так или так.

Comment: Ванга сейчас оффлайн. Без нее мы не поймем того, что вам, собственно, нужно от этого запроса! Но, на всякий случай, поинтересуйтесь о приоритетах логических операций.

Comment: ну, если непонятно, то зачем постить коммент? значит, идите учитесь понимать :) я пишу в надежде найти тех, кому понятно.

Comment: Тогда вам не сюда, а на "Битву экстрасенсов". Из вашего вопроса совершенно непонятно, _что именно_ вы хотите получить в результате запроса.

Comment: @Ozim Комменты - для уточнения вопроса. Не дай бог с вами в команду, доку написать не сумеете совершенно.

Comment: @Ozim. Вам @Free_ze написал дело - вы толком не объяснили чего вы добиваетесь от запроса. Не понятно ведь! Объясните, что вы хотите получить в итоге. И учтите - OR тут, как по мне - лишний. Для каждой таблицы сравнения происходят отдельно. Мне кажется, что нужно так:

    SELECT i.*, p.* FROM images i, products p WHERE p.product_id=i.product_id AND p.timeadded=1393282800 AND i.color!=0 AND p.active=1 AND p.maker_id=32 AND p.timeadded!=0 AND (i.product_id IN (3598))

Comment: @ikoolik спасибо большое! Оно :) сконвертируйте коммент в ответ, я приму.
@fori1ton если Вы не можете понять, это не значит, что никто не может.

Comment: @Ozim если вы не можете объяснить, значит вам не ответят. Все комменты написанные выше правдивы. Я тоже не смог бы с вами работать в команде! Вы даже текст ошибки не написали!!! @ikoolik просто повезло, что он сванговал удачно....

Comment: вы невнимательно читали, господа. Во-первых, я написал

Мне важно, чтобы было соблюдено условие: выбрать то, что было до OR (i.product_id IN (3598)), а также, выбрать OR (i.product_id IN (3598))

что тут непонятно?

Во-вторых, я написал 

если запрос без OR (i.product_id IN (3598)) - то все работает нормально, а с этим куском выводится очень много всего (может даже вообще все записи).

Comment: @Ozim Я вам сразу сказал, что проблема, скорее всего, в приоритете операций.
Судя по вашему "пояснению", у вас так все изначально в запросе и написано: сначала отрабатываются все условия по с AND, затем идет OR.
Понятное дело, что можно было повтыкать в условия и попытаться мысленно восстановить структуру таблицы, понять, чего вы там хотели...но вот зачем этим заниматься, если суть вопроса в другом?

Comment: @Ozim, то что вы хотели чтоб всё работало без проблем, со всеми условиями мы поняли. Но мы не поняли что должно работать. Ход ваших мыслей, что вы выбирали с помощью этого запроса и куда пихали - надо было расписать ПОШАГОВО...:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что условие объединения таблиц  `p.product_id=i.product_id` игнорируется при добавлении условия с помощью **OR**.
Почитайте  про **JOIN** или преобразуйте условие в

```
WHERE p.product_id=i.product_id 
AND (
    p.timeadded=1393282800 
    AND i.color!=0 
    AND p.active=1 
    AND p.maker_id=32 
    AND p.timeadded!=0 
    OR i.product_id IN (3598)
)
```

Comment: Огромное мерси! :) вот так человек, без понтов, а четко по делу помог, берите пример, господа, ждущие Вангу.

Comment: @Ozim, а ты научись объяснять, и никто не будет Вангу ждать.

Answer (score 2):

групировать условия надо, как-то так:

```
SELECT i.*, p.* 
  FROM images i, 
       products p 
 WHERE p.product_id = i.product_id 
   AND (  p.product_id IN (3598)
       OR (  p.timeadded=1393282800 
         AND p.active = 1 
         AND p.maker_id = 32 
         AND p.timeadded != 0 
         AND i.color != 0 
          )
       )
```

Comment: спасибо, примерно тоже написал ikoolik

Answer (score 2):

А нужно получить одновременно по

```
p.product_id=i.product_id AND p.timeadded=1393282800 AND i.color!=0 AND p.active=1 AND p.maker_id=32 AND p.timeadded!=0
```

и по

```
OR (i.product_id IN (3598)) ?
```

Или результат должен быть либо по первому "большому" условию либо по второму?

Просто если надо получить в одной выборке записи сразу по первому "большому" условию и по второму, то думаю можно попробовать `UNION`.

```
SELECT i.*, p.* 
  FROM images i, products p 
  WHERE p.product_id=i.product_id 
  AND p.timeadded=1393282800 
  AND i.color!=0 
  AND p.active=1 
  AND p.maker_id=32 
  AND p.timeadded!=0
UNION
SELECT i.*, p.* 
  FROM images i, products p
  WHERE i.product_id IN (3598)
```

Это если я правильно понял.

Comment: вся проблема в том что во второй половине запроса не определена связть между таблицами и как результат вам выведется для одного продукта вся таблица `images`

Answer (score 1):

Условия по OR вообще, будут выполнены, в том случае, если хотя бы одно из них истинно, не говоря уж о том, что оно будет выполнено, если истинны оба. Как бы, примерчик:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field1=1 OR some_filed2=2
```

вернет все записи где some_filed1=1 и все записи где some_field2=2.
Даже если в одной записи и some_field1=1 и some_filed2=2 - ее тоже вернет, ведь как минимум одно из описанных условий верно. Обычно скобки помогают такие ситуации исправлять)